# OCaml: Embedding openGL in GTK

Tags: opengl, gtk, ocaml

I would like to embed openGL graphics in a GTK program in OCaml. Do you have any ideas on how to do this?

(EDIT) Tk seems to have the problem solved with [Togl](http://togl.sourceforge.net).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my ubuntu I have the package "liblablgtk2-gl-ocaml":

> $ apt-cache show liblablgtk2-gl-ocaml-dev
>   ....
>   This package contains the development files of lablgtk for libraries using
>   GtkGL.

Never used it, but I guess that the GtkGL bindings is exactly what you need.

Comment: Yes, it seems to be what I need. I couldn't find that for MacOS or source code, though. Any idea where I could find it?

Comment: Check this: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/lucid/+source/lablgtk2/2.14.0+dfsg-2build1/+files/lablgtk2_2.14.0+dfsg.orig.tar.gz I'm not sure but there must be sources for gtkGl as well.

Comment: Yes there are.  "ml_gtkgl.c" e.t.c.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't seem to be able to install `lablgtk2-2.14.0+dfsg`. The `./configure` part goes fine but I get an error when I do `make world`. The error is `ml_gobject.c:293: error: conflicting types for ‘g_value_get_variant’
/opt/local/include/glib-2.0/gobject/gvaluetypes.h:230: error: previous declaration of ‘g_value_get_variant’ was here`. Any ideas?