# Any OCaml bindings for GtkGlExt? If not, how can I write them?

Tags: opengl, gtk, ocaml

I currently have two separate programs: (1) a GTK GUI; (2) a Glut application with openGL 3D graphics. However, I'd like to have the openGL part as some widget embedded in the GUI I have.

I have noticed [GtkGlExt](http://projects.gnome.org/gtkglext/) is exactly what I need, but unfortunately there are no OCaml bindings mentioned on its web pages.

My questions are:

(1) Do you know if there are any such bindings lost somewhere in cyberspace? (I have found a similar [discussion](http://www.mail-archive.com/gtk-app-devel-list@gnome.org/msg10976.html) from 2008 so I would hope after 3 years something would have happened.)

(2) If there aren't any bindings, how difficult would it be to produce these bindings and where would it be a good place to start? How much of the original C libraries would I have to undestand? (I haven't done any C calls from OCaml so far.)

(3) Alternatively, do you know of any other out-of-the-box package I could use? (I have attempted to install [gtkglarea](http://linux.maruhn.com/sec/gtkglarea.html) on OSX but I had errors which I couldn't solve and gave up. I've also tried to install [lablgtk2-2.14.0+dfsg](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/lucid/+source/lablgtk2/2.14.0+dfsg-2build1/+files/lablgtk2_2.14.0+dfsg.orig.tar.gz) but got the errors described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4933975/ocaml-embedding-opengl-in-gtk).)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard solution is to use the LablGTK's OpenGL support.  I know of no bindings to other solutions such as gtkglext.  If you want to write your own bindings, in general it isn't overly difficult, does take some work and thought.  You'll at least need to understand enough of the underlying C library to safely bridge with OCaml, which varies greatly with the library's interface.  Since GtkGLExt is Glib-based, so you'll have the blessing and curse of being able to build on existing experience in the community with binding GLib/GTK libraries, and needing to understand enough of how Lablgtk2 works to make your bindings integrate with it.  This is possible, but not exactly trivial and I don't recall seeing any good documentation on binding new GTK libraries to help you get started.

Your error in the other question looks like you're trying to hand-compile - have you tried building the GODI package for lablgtk with OpenGL enabled? It may have patches and/or build options to make it work. Alternatively, does MacPorts, which it looks like you're using from the `/opt/local` path, have OCaml and lablgtk packages?

**Another option**: There's another option I commonly use when I need access to facilities from an unbound library.  Rather than writing bindings for the library, I'll write the logic needing that library in C and expose a minimal interface back to my OCaml code.  In the GtkGLExt case, it's probably just a matter of creating initialization, teardown, and start/stop context calls that do the underlying work with the C API and return the OpenGL context or whatever is necessary.  You'll still need to do some work to figure out how to get the right GTK object from the OCaml object, and how to pass back whatever is needed for LablGL to work, but it's typically easier than creating real bindings.

Comment: @MichaelE I looked in more detail to what would be needed to do the bindings and it is much more work than I thought. So, I'll drop it for now. I *have* used GODI; I tried with GL support first but even a simple "test configuration" in GODI gives: `> checking for GTKGL... no
> configure: error: gl enforced but no support found
> Error: Exec error: File /Users/surikator/godi/build/godi/godi-lablgtk2/./../../mk/bsd.pkg.mk, line 1022: Command returned with non-zero exit code`. It seems I'm missing GTKGL... is that an option I need to turn on while installing GTK itself?

Comment: @MichaelE I currently have GTK-OSX installed with MacPorts. I'm not sure how to have GTKGL for this variant of GTK. And that seems to be what's missing for GODI to be able to proceed with its installation of lablgtk2 with GL support.

Comment: @Surikator I think the LablGTK support uses gtkglarea, but I'm not 100% sure.  You'll also need LablGL installed, but GODI will take care of that. It could be that gtkglarea has not been ported to GTK-OSX.  There's been a bug report for a while to add GL support directly to GTK+, but I don't think there's been much traction on it yet.

Comment: @MichaelE I have LablGL installed in GODI and always had during these attempts. I can't install gtkglarea for some reason. It says `:info:build gdkgl.c:22:22: error: gdk/gdkx.h: No such file or directory`.

Comment: @Surikator That error indicates that it cannot find the GTK+/X11 bridge (which is true, since you have GTK+-OSX installed).  You'll either need to somehow tell gtkglarea to use a different backend, if that is possible, or to use the X11 version of GTK+.  It may be that gtkglarea does not yet support the OSX/Quartz backend.  It needs backend-specific support code in order to know how to set up OpenGL contexts for windows/widgets.

Comment: @MichaelE Yep, I remember having a requirement of X11 somewhere else in the process also. I really prefer GTK-OSX for look and feel, that's why I was trying to have a go with GtkGlExt and not gtkglarea. I don't think gtkglarea can work outside X11 and that's the reason I wasn't able to make it work. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Surikator I've updated my answer with another option that I use in situations like this. I don't know why I didn't think of it earlier. Basically, don't write real bindings - write a minimal interface and do the real GtkGLExt work in C.